# django rest framework limit_choices_to attribute ignored?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using the DjangoRest Framework with 2 models *DeviceType* and *Channel*. Now *Channel* has a ForeignKeyField pointing to a *DeviceType*. No problem so far.
But now I don't want all *DeviceTypes* to be selectable when adding or editing a *Channel* but only the *DeviceTypes* that have their *usesChannels* field set to True.
So I used the *limit_Choices_to* attribute but somehow that doesn't seem to work. No matter what I do, I alway get a list with all *DeviceTypes* including the ones with *usesChannels* set to False

This is my code:

**models.py**

```
class DeviceType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    usesChannels = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.name)

class Channel(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(DeviceType, limit_choices_to={'usesChannels': True})
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    channelNr = models.IntegerField()
```

**serializers.py**

```
class DeviceTypeSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DeviceType
        fields = ('url', 'name', 'usesChannels')

class ChannelSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Channel
        flieds = ('url', 'type', 'name', 'channelNr')
```

I used the ForeignKey.limit_choices_to example from [This link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.10/ref/models/fields/)

**Edit:** I use the DRF browsable API to add, edit and remove data.

**Answer:** After struggling with this for a few days I found a working solution:

**models.py**

```
class DeviceType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    usesChannels = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.name)

class Channel(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(DeviceType)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    channelNr = models.IntegerField()
```

**serializers.py**

```
class DeviceTypeSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DeviceType
        fields = ('url', 'name', 'usesChannels')

class ChannelSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    type = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=DeviceType.objects.filter(usesChannels=True))
    class Meta:
        model = Channel
        flieds = ('url', 'type', 'name', 'channelNr')
```

**Edit:** For completeness I'll add the views too

**Views.py:**

```
class DeviceTypeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = DeviceType.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DeviceTypeSerializer

class ChannelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Channel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ChannelSerializer
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the foreign key options that you are seeing are in the Django Admin UI or the DRF browsable API view?

Comment: Hi Redskins, thanks for helping. The options I see are in the DRF browsable API view.

Comment: Could you show me your views.py, please?

Comment: Hi serv-bot, I don't know if you were helping out or facing the same problem but i've added the views. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this problem today. I believe it does indeed completely ignore the attribute; at least I couldn't find any reference to it in DRF's code.

So I "solved" the problem by adding `Serializer.__init__` constructor and within it the following function / code:

```
class MySerializer(Serializers.Serializer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        def limit_choices_to(field_name):
            fld = self.fields[field_name]
            fld.queryset = fld.queryset.filter(**Flight._meta.get_field(field_name).get_limit_choices_to())

        limit_choices_to('my_field')
```

Comment: FYI, DRF 3.9.1 introduced support for limit_choices_to.